# WCF integration with Spark

Tags: java, c#, .net, wcf, apache-spark

We have services running on the WCF infrastructure. WCF service client is .net window form application. For some time and resource intensive tasks, we are trying to integrate WCF services with the Apache Spark. WCF service should call Apache Spark for executing the task. Apache Spark supports java not C#. We need some way by which we can call Spark from the WCF service for data processing. We are trying add the spark in plug-gable way. If any new technology comes in near future then we can plug that easily in place of spark.

One way could be using the Message Queues where WCF puts task on queue and spark gets the task from queue and execute the task.  Message Queuing approach adds another layer in the architecture.

a. Is message queue architecture is an elegant solution? Pros and cons ?

b. What could be other ways to integrate the Spark with WCF?

Comment: What about using https://github.com/Microsoft/SparkCLR?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant : we run a Java server and call Spark via the command line. I did not find that Spark was suited to run in our web server (too much dependencies that overlapped). A  interesting alternative may be https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver but I have yet to try it